# Yii2 - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: string, model, yii2

i have te following code to embed post of facebook in a web page.

```
<?php echo FacebookPlugin::widget(['type'=>FacebookPlugin::POST, 'settings' => ['href'=> $facebook ]]);?>
```

The problem is that ['href'=> $facebook ], does not accept $facebook variable that has stored a query from a table containing links to post of facebook.

It always gives error - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

**I have tried srtval(), string() and print_r() to convert but it always throws error. **

Any solutions ??

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
 ['href'=> implode('', $facebook)]
```